# unable to bind listbox in winform on tabControl1_Selected event?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

**MainForm.cs**

```
 public MainForm() 
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     tabControl1.Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(tabControl1_Selected);
 }

 private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
 {
     //bind listbox
     MyUserControl obj = new MyUserControl();
     obj.LoadListBox();
     obj.Refresh();
 }
```

inside MyUserControl.cs

```
 public void LoadListBox()
 {
     listBox1.Items.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <object[]> (File.ReadAllText("MyData.json")));
 }
```

Why not refreshed or bind? In debug mode it is showing data but not shown on UI Form, any clue?

Comment: What do you mean with reflect?

Comment: corrected i mean bind..

Comment: Are you sure that Json serializing returns any data?

Comment: Is listbox control already binded with another data when tab control's selected event triggered?

Comment: I'm sure about data is coming inside `listBox1.Items` as debugger shows data but i think  problem is `bind listbox code is inside Usercontrol - may be because of that it is not refreshed or update` - edited question

Comment: @Uğur Aldanmaz it is null when Form load but once I click on `tab` it is raising event method going inside method `LoadListBox` bind data (shows in debugger) but unable to show it on UI back

Comment: Do you add the `MyUserControl` instance to the MainForm? Your edited question does not seem like do that. You should add user control to somewhere to reflect on UI.

Comment: what is add the `MyUserControl `instance? is this not work ? `  MyUserControl obj = new MyUserControl();`

Comment: I mean like that code:
 `MyUserControl obj = new MyUserControl();
this.Controls.Add(obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the user control instance to the winform.

```
 private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
 {
     //bind listbox
     MyUserControl obj = new MyUserControl();
     obj.LoadListBox();
     obj.Refresh();
     this.Controls.Add(obj); //Add control instance to the winform.
 }
```

I suggest that, add a `Panel` control to the form and add user control to this panel. You need clear the panel before adding the user control. But it depends on your requirement. Maybe you do not need to add control every time. So you should write your codes accordingly.

```
 private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
 {
     //I guess you have a Panel control named as pnl.
     pnl.Controls.Clear(); //Clear all child control from panel.
     MyUserControl obj = new MyUserControl();
     obj.LoadListBox();
     obj.Refresh();
     pnl.Controls.Add(obj); //Add control instance to the panel.
 }
```

Comment: still no luck with ` this.Controls.Add(obj); //Add control instance to the winform.` it is not binding